# c#: Distance from point to a line segment (in longitude and latitude)

Tags: c#, line, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a position (A) in longitude and latitude.

I have a line segment with start (B) and end (C) points in longitude and latitude.

What I am trying to calculate is the shortest distance from A to line B<->C.
In other words the distance from A to the closest point (on line BC) in meters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the shortest distance on the surface of a sphere or in 3D space? Does the line follow the surface of a sphere?

Comment: I note that first off, your "line segment" is probably no such thing; presumably you wish the locus of points between the two end points to lie on the great circle on the surface of the Earth, not on the straight line through the body of the Earth. That means that it is an *arc*, not a line segment. Second, if that is the case, then the problem is under-specified. Two antipodal points have infinitely many great circle arcs between them; which one do you want to choose?